# No match for 'operator='std::vector<int>' and '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<int> >

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

I am receiving the following error while trying to compile the code.

```
Error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'std::vector<int>' and '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<int> >::value_type {aka int}')|
----- >>>>>     vertex[j] = trip.id[new_trip_id];
```

```cpp
struct cardata{

std::vector<int> x;
std::vector<int> y;
std::vector<int> id;
std::vector<int> limit;
std::vector<bool> status;

};

struct tripdata{

std::vector<int> x;
std::vector<int> y;
std::vector<int> id;
std::vector<double> length;
std::vector<double> distance;
std::vector<double> travtime;
std::vector<double> trav;
std::vector<bool> status;
}; 

std::vector<std::vector<int> > Ridesharing::TAB(std::vector<std::vector<int> > input){

int new_trip_id;
int new_car_id;
for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++ ) { 
rideout.push_back(std::vector<int>());
    if (input[i].size() > 1){

            new_car_id = input[i][0];
            vector<int> vertex[0] = 0; //// Test if car.id[2] = 2 = new_car_id
            vector<double> x[0] = 0;
            vector<double> y[0] = 0;
            vector<double> demand[0] = 1;
            vector<double> ready[0] = 0;
            vector<double> dueDate[0] = 7284;
            vector<double> unload[0] = 0;

        for ( unsigned int j = 1; j < input[i].size(); j++ ){ 
            new_trip_id = input[i][j] - car.id.size(); 
            vertex[j] = trip.id[new_trip_id]; 
            x[j] = trip.distance[new_trip_id].push_back(abs(car.x[new_car_id] - trip.x.[new_trip_id]) + abs(car.y[new_car_id] - trip.y.[new_trip_id]) + trip.length[new_trip_id]);
            y[j] = trip.travtime[new_trip_id].push_back((abs(car.x[new_car_id] - trip.x.[new_trip_id]) + abs(car.y[new_car_id] - trip.y.[new_trip_id]) + (trip.length[new_trip_id]))/trip.trav[new_trip_id]);
            demand[j] = 1; //// Note: x, y values will be rewritten for each cluster
            ready[j] = 0;
            dueDate[j] = 7284;
            unload[j] = (rand() % 10 + 1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `vertex[j] = trip.id[new_trip_id]; `. What is `trip` here?

Comment: It is "tripdata trip;"

Comment: Also `vector<int> vertex[0] = 0;` What does this mean?

Comment: I am assigning 0 as a value to this vector vertex[0].

Comment: You can assign value to particular index of the vector.I think you want `vector<int> vertex(1); vertex[0]=0;`

Comment: Yes, I am assigning 0 to vector index 0 and trip.id[new_trip_id] to index 1 and so on using for loop. This is where I get the error.

Comment: To make your code conform to some C++ standard (C++98,C++03,C++11,C++14)
recompile it with appropriate options e.g. `g++ -Wall -std=c++11 -pedantic -o prog main.cpp`. Then fix it to remove the compiler warnings that you see and your problem will be solved.

Comment: I am using c++11 option, but I am still stuck at vertex[ j ] = trip.id [new_trip_id];

Comment: You should have receive something like this: warning: ISO C++ forbids zero-size array 'vertex' [-Wpedantic]
             vector<int> vertex[0] = 0; //// Test if car.id[2] = 2 = new_car_id

Comment: You can probably ask the same question on the same error, with a much simpler code example... best thing would be to create the minimal code example ("MCE") that shows the compilation error that you got. While creating the MCE, the compilation error / bug / anomaly may disappear and the question may be answered just by some coding. And if not, then others can much easily assist.

Comment: @Far. As I said, compile with `-Wall -std=c++11 -pedantic`, then fix the code to remove the new warnings.